# Is it safe to use "Safety" as a schema name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-design, schema

I was considering using "Safety" as a new schema name in SQL Server. In SSMS, the term `Safety` is colored as a keyword, but this term is not listed as a reserved keyword in the BOL. The database does not complain if I create and use it, but is there any reason why I should avoid using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "safety" was used as a PivotTable service option back in the days of SQL 2000.  It's still around for backwards compatibility:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237323(v=sql.80).aspx

Otherwise, it's okay to use as a schema name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, completely. If the name suits the usage area - feel free to use it.